# How to compute accuracy and the confusion matrix using K-fold cross-validation?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

I tried to do K-fold cross-validation with K=30 folds, with one confusion matrix for each fold. How to compute the accuracy and the confusion matrix to the model with confidence interval?
Could someone help me?

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

UNSW = pd.read_csv('/home/sec/Desktop/CEFET/tudao.csv')

previsores = UNSW.iloc[:,UNSW.columns.isin(('sload','dload',
                                                   'spkts','dpkts','swin','dwin','smean','dmean',
'sjit','djit','sinpkt','dinpkt','tcprtt','synack','ackdat','ct_srv_src','ct_srv_dst','ct_dst_ltm',
 'ct_src_ltm','ct_src_dport_ltm','ct_dst_sport_ltm','ct_dst_src_ltm')) ].values


classe= UNSW.iloc[:, -1].values


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(
previsores, classe, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)

print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
#((90, 4), (90,))
print(X_test.shape, y_test.shape)
#((60, 4), (60,))

logmodel = LogisticRegression()
logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)
print(previsores.shape)


########K FOLD
print('########K FOLD########K FOLD########K FOLD########K FOLD')
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

kf = KFold(n_splits=30, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
kf.get_n_splits(previsores)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(previsores):

    X_train, X_test = previsores[train_index], previsores[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = classe[train_index], classe[test_index]

    logmodel.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print (confusion_matrix(y_test, logmodel.predict(X_test)))
print(10* '#')
```

Answer (score 4):

For accuracy, I would use the function `cross_val_score` that does exactly what you are looking for. It outputs a list of 30 validation accuracies and you can then compute their mean, standard deviation, etc and create some kind of a confidence interval (mean +- 2*std)
.

Since confusion matrix cannot be seen as a performance metric (not a single number but a matrix) I would recommend creating a list and then iteratively just append it with a corresponding validation confusion matrix (currently you just print it). At the end, you can use this list to extract a lot of interesting information.

UPDATE:

```
...
...
cm_holder = []
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(previsores):
    X_train, X_test = previsores[train_index], previsores[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = classe[train_index], classe[test_index]

    logmodel.fit(X_train, y_train)
    cm_holder.append(confusion_matrix(y_test, logmodel.predict(X_test))))
```

Note that the `len(cm_holder)` = 30 and each of the elements is an array of `shape=(n_classes, n_classes)`.

Comment: @Jan K: Could u help me with the confusion matrix?

Comment: @Mohammed Kashif: I would like a help with the confusion matrix!

Comment: @LaurindaSouza what exactly do you need help with regarding the confusion matrix ?

Comment: @ Mohammed Kashif: I dont know how to calculate confusion matrix with k-fold. I neet it with confidence interval!

Comment: See the update. However, it is not clear what you mean by "confidence interval on confusion matrix ".

Comment: @Jan K: I would like to show the final confusion matrix with 95% confidence!!

Comment: @Jan K: The only metric when u use cross validation is accuracy?

Comment: @JanK: Something like compute the average of the confusion matrices with confidence interval!

Comment: My point is that confusion matrix is not a single number. It is a matrix. Plus it represent absolute counts so if your validation sets are not stratified then these absolute counts may vary. But whatever, consider posting a question on Cross Validated. I feel I cannot help you at this point anymore.